# Docker compose: ensure volume mounted before running CMD

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've built a container that has nginx and some config for HTTPS inside it.
The certificates are generated automatically by another container using https://letsencrypt.org/. The nginx container also provides some default self signed certificates to use until the certbot container has generated the good ones. This is how my config looks:

```yaml
version: '2'

services:
  # Nginx, the master of puppets, listens in port 80
  nginx:
    image: mycompany/nginx:v1.2.8
    depends_on: [api, admin, front, postgres, redis, certbot]
    ports: ["80:80", "443:443"]
    volumes:
      - acme_challenge:/var/www/acme_challenge
      - ssl_certs:/var/certs
    environment:
      ACME_CHALLENGE_PATH: /var/www/acme_challenge

      # Where will the container put the default certs
      DEFAULT_SSL_CERTS_PATH: /var/default_certs

      # Use temporary self signed keys by default
      SSL_CERTIFICATE:     /var/default_certs/selfsigned.crt
      SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY: /var/default_certs/selfsigned.key

      # Once certbot generates certs I change config to this and recreate the container
      # SSL_CERTIFICATE:     /var/cerst/mycompany.com/fullchain.pem
      # SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY: /var/certs/mycompany.com/privkey.pem

  # Certbot renews SSL certificates periodically
  certbot:
    image: mycompany/certbot:v1.0.9
    restart: on-failure:3
    environment:
      - WEBROOT_PATH=/var/www/acme_challenge
      - SIGNING_EMAIL=info@yavende.com
      - DOMAINS=mycompany.com, api.mycompany.com
    volumes:
      - acme_challenge:/var/www/acme_challenge
      - ssl_certs:/etc/letsencrypt/live

volumes:
  acme_challenge:
  ssl_certs:
```

This is more or less how stuff works:

- The nginx container is configured to use some self-signed certificates
- `docker compose up -d` launches certbot and nginx on parallel.
- Meanwhile certbot runs a process to generate the certificates. Assume this succeeded.
- After a while, I attach to the nginx container and run `ls /var/certs` and the certbot generated certs are there. Nice!
- I modify the configuration of nginx container to use those new certificates (via env vars SSL_CERTIFICATE*) and recreate the container.
- Nginx fails to run because the files are not there, even when I know that the files are there (checked with a lot of methods)

**I suspect that the command of the image (`CMD`) is run regardless of whether the volumes where yet attached to the container or not.
Is this true? Should I write some bash to wait until this files are present?**

Comment: I think that the nignx process search for the certs meanwhile the certbot is processing them. That is because the depends_on only waits container to start, regardless whether it finished creating certs. As a workaround you can modify the nginx CMD to something that sleep for a while and then run nginx.

Comment: There's no race condition because first I tell nginx to use fallback self signed certs. Once the certs have been generated I change the config to use the new certs and re-create the nginx container.

Comment: It's unlikely the volumes are missing, docker would normally error for something like that. You can confirm at startup by replacing your command with `CMD ["sh", "-c", "ls -l /var/certs; nginx -g daemon off"]`

Comment: When you say you recreate the container, can you be more specific what you mean? I've run into a few scenarios where it seemed like the container would be recreated, but on further digging, it turned out things did not work until I stopped and removed the container, then `up` again.

Comment: I change the config for env variables in the YAML file and then run `docker compose up -d
 --no-deps nginx`. Docker tells me the container is being recreated.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: this is a plug for my own docker image.

I have made a very nice docker image based on nginx for this exact purpose, with features such as automatic letsencrypt management, http basic auth, virtual hosts etc. managed through passing a simple json config through an environment variable. I use it in production, so it is stable.

You can find it [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/tcjn/json-webrouter/), and it's at `tcjn/json-webrouter` on docker hub.

All you need to do is pass something like this in to the CONFIG environment variable:

```
{"servers": [
          {"ServerName": "example.com", "Target": "192.168.2.52:32407", "Https": true},
          {"ServerName": "*.example.com", "Target": "192.168.2.52:4444", "Https": true},
          {"ServerName": "secret.example.com", "Target": "192.168.2.52:34505", "Https": true, "Auth": {"Realm": "Login for secret stuff", "Set": "secret_users"}}
        ], "auth": {
          "secret_users": {"bob": "HASH GENERATED BY openssl passwd"}
        }}
```

And yes, it is just as simple as `"Https": true`. You can find all the possible options in the [github repo](https://github.com/techninja1008/json-webrouter).

Comment: Sounds good, doesn't answer the question though. Will give it a look.